# Facing an error after getting login: Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing a problem while fetching data after getting logged in. Please have a look at my code. I am a fresher in CodeIgniter so please help me.

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in
>   CodeIgniter

**This is my Controller:**

```
public function login_function()
{
     $this->load->database();

     // Load the model  
     $this->load->model('login_model');  

     // Load the method of model  
     $records = $this->login_model->can_login();  

     // Return the data in view  
     if ($records === false)
     {
           $this->session->set_flashdata("message", "invalid user"); 
           redirect('Main_controller', 'refresh');  
     } else {
           $this->session->set_userdata('id', $records['id']);
           $data['f'] = $records;
           $this->load->view('user-home', $data); 
     }
}
```

**This is my Model:**

```
function can_login()
{   
     $email=$this->input->post('email');
     $password=$this->input->post('password');

     // Data is retrieve from this query 
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->where('email', $email);
     $this->db->where('password', $password); 

     $query1 = $this->db->get('registration');

     $result = $query1->result(); 

     if (!empty($result)){
         return $query1->row_array();
     } else {
         return false;
     }
 }
```

**And this is my View:**

```
<?php foreach ($f->result() as $row) { ?>
    <h1><?php echo $row->first_name; ?></h1><br /><br />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Did you load the database class as shown in the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html#initializing-the-database-class)?

Comment: Before $query1 = $this->db->get('registration'); do echo 'rows'. $query1->num_rows(); and report what you get

Comment: yes, I did.But still it is not working.

Comment: alex : A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: query1

Filename: models/login_model.php

Comment: it is printing 'rows1' when I put echo 'rows'. $query1->num_rows(); after  $query1 = $this->db->get('registration');

Comment: Looks like you are storing plan un-hashed password in your db read up on http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes from your View. You call the `result()` method on `$f` which is the result of your `can_login()` function.

**`$f` takes two values *(according to your model)*:**

- `false` if no result;
- an array (`row_array()`) if results are found.

The problem is that you call the `result()` method on a `row_array()` method (something like `$query1->row_array()->result()`), which is wrong.

**Solution:** You should return your `$result` variable in your model. Then, in your view, you can use this code to display your results:

```
foreach ($f as $row) // $f = $query->result() as you saved it in your model
{
    echo $row->first_name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to use code below in your model

```
if(!empty($result)){
return $query1->row_array();
         } else{
            return false;
         }
```

just try `return $query->result_array;` or `return $query->result;`

it will return false if there is no result!